# Payout address format has changed?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, address-generation, bitcoin-qt-setup, bitcoincore-gui

When I run bitcoin-qt, it sets up a default wallet. When I ask it for the recipient address for this wallet, I was expecting something like **1F**Gasdfasdfasdf123asdfasdf. However what it actually provides is **BC1QNZ**asdfasdfasdf... In fact there seems to be no way to induce bitcoin-qt to divulge an address in the form of **1FG**asdfasdfasdf123asdf... Can someone clear up what the BC prefix is all about? I'm using the main Bitcoin blockchain (350 GB in size), not Bitcoin Cash..

Answer (score 2):

This is a [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) native segwit address.

If you unselect the "Generate native segwit (Bech32) address" checkbox in bitcoin-qt, you'll get a P2SH 3xxx address instead. Most senders these days support sending the BIP173 addresses though, which are cheaper for you to use.

The GUI no longer supports creation of legacy 1xxx addresses by default. You can override this by starting bitcoin-qt with the `-addresstype=legacy` command-line option. There is no reason for preferring these, except for test purposes.

Comment: If I want to run a solo mining experiment, don't I need the 1xxx format to give to bfgminer or cgminer as the generate-to address?

Comment: I have no idea, but if you really need a 1xxx address, you can use RPC or the debug console: `getnewaddress "" legacy`.